# How can I set a url that would work with OAuth?

Tags: g-suite, google-compute-engine, oauth

I have:

- a domain hosted outside google (englishcampus.com.br)
- a VM instance in Google Compute Engine running an application, with a static IP
- a subdomain (erp.englishcampus.com.br) pointing to that VM, which is working fine

But as I'm trying to authenticate Google API (OAuth), I get an error message:

"Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Raw IP addresses not allowed: http://104.197.50.68:8069/google_account/authentication"

...showing that one cannot use an IP address to redirect. On the API credential I put "http://erp.englishcampus.com.br/google_account/authentication", assuming that erp.englishcampus.com.br points to the VM.

My question is: how can I have the VM responding under an URL, instead of the static IP address, so that the OAuth process work?

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the VM an [A record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_record) for erp.englishcampus.com.br. This is how you make a domain name point to a ip address.

Comment: I see. This is working. But when I invoke the OAuth redirection, it rejects the URI because it has an IP address inside it: "http://104.197.50.68:8069/google_account/authentication".

Comment: the A record is working but the call resolves back to the VM IP.

Comment: Don't use the IP address as part of your URI, use the A record instead.